# JDBC JMeter , parameterize a table

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I was looking to hit a query from JMeter JDBC which is like

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS TEST_NUMBER FROM TABLE(:B1))
```

where B1 is a table of values
any idea how to go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a JMeter variable (also can be a property), for example B1 with your table name as its value

And inside JDBC Request, use it as `${B1}`, and JMeter will replace it with table name:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS TEST_NUMBER FROM ${B1}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but my problem is how to get that table from, or do I create that table in jmeter?

Comment: @user13718924 it depends , you can build table by just selecting values, e.g. `select 1,2,3 from dual`

Comment: whats the other option?
really appreciate if any links with e.g. on that

Comment: @user13718924 just use ?Update Statement with table creation as `create table B1 (b varchar(1))`